# google_new_transError: Failed to connect. Probable cause: timeout?

Tags: python, google-translate

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator 

translator= google_translator()

translated = translator.translate("i am a boy", lang_tgt = 'fr')
translated_back = translator.translate(translated, lang_tgt = 'en')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library uses requests to the web interface. In case of overuse Google blocks you for a while because for an application you have to use Google Translate API. The problem may be there.